# creating a matrix from a smaller "key" matrix

Tags: r

let's say that I have a smaller, correlation matrix ("the key"):

```
  a    b     c  
a 1.0  0.0   0.2  
b 0.0  1.0   0.1  
c 0.2  0.1   1.0
```

I want to use this key on another data frame/matrix, with ID's (a, b, c), to make a larger matrix.

For example, this example data frame:

```
sex age id 
F   20  a
F   22  b
M   23  b
M   18  a
F   12  c
```

would turn into this larger correlation matrix using the above "key":

```
  a    b   b   a   c
a 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.2
b 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.1
b 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.1
a 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.2
c 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.2 1.0
```

what's a way to do this, and what's a way to do this computationally efficient, given a much larger data frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

R allows subsetting by names:

```
mat_cor[df1$id,df1$id]
    a   b   b   a   c
a 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.2
b 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.1
b 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.1
a 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.2
c 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.2 1.0
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("F", 
                                                                 "M"), class = "factor"), age = c(20L, 22L, 23L, 18L, 12L), id = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                             2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("sex", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "age", "id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
mat_cor <- structure(c(1, 0, 0.2, 0, 1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 
                                                         3L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "c")))
```

Comment: this works, thanks!

Comment: but is there a way to do this w/ a bigger df1? My df is 500,000 long and it crashes.

Comment: 500k rows or columns?

Comment: How many columns? Instead of me asking these questions, can you please add the full dimensions of all of the objects you are dealing with, including the correlation matrix

Comment: sure. my correlation matrix is 91x91, and dataset is 500k row and 10 columns

Comment: So you want a final data frame with dimensions 45,500,000 x 45,500,000? How do you expect a non-supercomputer to store this information? Computational efficiency isn't the point here. You need space.